# would complexity of constraint satisfaction problem bound the constrained optimization problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, constraint-satisfaction

If a constraint satisfaction problem $x \in Y$ is NP-Complete.
Can I conclude that the optimization problem $^* =\text{argmax}_x (x)$ s.t. $x \in Y$ is also NP-Complete?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained description of the task: what is the input, and the desired output, and how is the input represented?  I don't know what is meant by "a constraint satisfaction problem $x \in Y$" - it's hard to tell what is fixed as part of the problem and what is the input, and it's not clear how $Y$ is represented.  Similarly for the optimization problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, no optimization problem can be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete since all $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems are in $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$ only contains **decision** problems.

Comment: Or can I conclude that there is no polynomial solution to the optimization problem?

Comment: Are the domains of the variables finite?

Comment: Yes, all the variables are finite

Comment: Then also, no. As far as we know there might be a polynomial-time algorithm for the optimization version. Indeed, any poly-time algorithm for the decision version of your problem probably implies the existence of a poly-time algorithm for the optimization version (guess the variables one at a time) and it might be the case that $P=NP$. Assuming $P \neq NP$ then there is no poly-time algorithm for the optimization version as it would imply the existence of a poly-time algorithm for decision version, and hence $P=NP$, resulting in a contradiction.